# Need custom groups based on strings in ssrs

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Ok so I can do this in crystal reports but my users can not view live data which is a problem so I want to move the report to ssrs.

What I have is pretty simple. It's a report that lists businesses and number of clients. I need two groups one that has a specific business name like "Business1*" and the second group has businesses with an identifier at the end like "*[1234]".
The rest of the business can all be in one group and each group needs a total at the end. My issue is with creating this custom groupings.

Comment: Could you add your code to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are doing this in SQL then you can have a calculated field in your SQL statement to impose a sort order:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN BusinessName LIKE 'Business1%' THEN 1 WHEN BusinessName LIKE '%[1234]' THEN 2 ELSE 3 END AS SortOrder, *
FROM MyTable
ORDER BY SortOrder
```